# AngularJS - set selected value in dropdown list where value matches with another object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please see my plunkr below

https://plnkr.co/edit/8xjmL9?p=preview

This what my $scope.data looks like

```
$scope.data = [  
   {  
      "projectedStart":"2016-12-14T00:00:00"     
   },
   {  
      "projectedStart":"2017-01-04T00:00:00"      
   },
   {  
      "projectedStart":"2017-01-11T00:00:00"      
   }   
];
```

This is what my scope.possibleDates look like

```
$scope.possibleDates = [  
   {  
      "projectedStartDate":"2016-12-07T00:00:00",
      "dateName":"December - Week 1"
   },
   {  
      "projectedStartDate":"2016-12-14T00:00:00",
      "dateName":"December - Week 2"
   },
   {  
      "projectedStartDate":"2016-12-21T00:00:00",
      "dateName":"December - Week 3"
   },
   {  
      "projectedStartDate":"2016-12-28T00:00:00",
      "dateName":"December - Week 4"
   },
   {  
      "projectedStartDate":"2017-01-04T00:00:00",
      "dateName":"January - Week 1 (20/10)"
   },
   {  
      "projectedStartDate":"2017-01-11T00:00:00",
      "dateName":"January - Week 2 (20/10)"
   }
]
```

This is what my select looks like which is obviously wrong

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>                  
      <tr>
        <th >Projected Date</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control"
                            ng-model="selectedValue"
                            ng-init="selectedValue = {{data.projectedStart == dates.projectedStartDate}}"
                            ng-options="dates.dateName for dates in possibleDates">
                 </select>
            </td>
        </tr>                                               
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to display a dropdown with a list of all the $scope.possibleDates's dateName property which is fine, but I want to have selected the value that matches with the 'projectedStart' in $scope.Data

Comment: Can you show your `ng-repeat` statement?

Comment: I've updated the question with the whole table so you can see the ng-repeat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think there is a need for defining a new model using ng-init and the way of usage is also wrong. You need to bind model which you want to update through the field. In this case it is `projectedStart` property of `data` array. So set that as your drop-down model. Now you need to set `ng-option` such that when `dateName` is selected, `projectedStart` property should go as value. 
The following code will be a good option for you.

```
<select class="form-control"
                        ng-model="d.projectedStart"
                        ng-options="dates.projectedStartDate as dates.dateName for dates in possibleDates">
                  </select>
```

I have updated the plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/Hd2UBec1ULK6XQ2H26hC?p=preview

Comment: thank you sir, you are a genius. this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to put `{{}}` inside `ng-init` expression.
Also, you need to use `d` instead of `data`, as you have defined `d in data` in `ng-repeat` statement

Just try this :

```
ng-init = "selectedValue = (d.projectedStart == dates.projectedStartDate)"
```

I guess this will work for you.

**Alternative :**

you can try this in place of your select statement.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedValue">
    <option ng-repeat="dates in possibleDates" ng-selected = "d.projectedStart == dates.projectedStartDate">dates.dateName</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have tried the alternative method but it only works if I remove the ng-model from the <select>. I want to keep the ng-model as I want to use ng-change as well. Unless there is another way to trigger a function call when the value here is changed.

Comment: and the first method is not working ?? There is less chance of that working, but just clearing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to this:

```
<select class="form-control"
      ng-model="selectedValue">
  <option ng-repeat="dates in possibleDates" selected="{{d.projectedStart == dates.projectedStartDate}}">{{dates.dateName}}</option>
</select>
```

You don't need `{{}}` inside your `ng-init` since it is evaluated by Angular itself.

Also for an item to be selected you need to set the value to one of the dates, your evaluation sets the `selectedValue` to `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control agentValue" style="padding: unset;" ng-model="selectedAgent[$index]" ng-change="setAgentID($index)">
    <option value="">Select Agent</option>
    <option ng-repeat="aList in agentlist" value="{{aList.LOGIN_ID}}">{{aList.FIRST_NAME}} {{aList.LAST_NAME}}</option>
</select>
```

this is the html code i have written (above is html)

```
for(var i= 0; i< $scope.datalist.length; i++){
    $scope.selectedAgent[i] = $scope.datalist[i].COLLECTION_AGENT_ID;
}
```

this my controller code this works fine for me